# Using "double" as counter variables in loops

Tags: c#, c++, loops, floating-point, counter

In a book I am currently reading, there is this excerpt:

> You can also use a floating-point
>   value as a loop counter. Here's an
>   example of a `for` loop with this kind
>   of counter:
>
> ```
> double a(0.3), b(2.5);
> for(double x = 0.0; x <= 2.0; x += 0.25)
>     cout << "\n\tx = " << x << "\ta*x + b = " << a*x + b;
> ```
>
> This code fragment calculates the
>   value of `a*x+b` for values of `x`
>   from `0.0` to `2.0`, in steps of
>   `0.25`; however, you need to take care
>   when using a floating-point counter in
>   a loop. Many decimal values cannot be
>   represented exactly in binary
>   floating-point form, so discrepancies
>   can build up with cumulative values.
>   This means that you should not code a
>   for loop such that ending the loop
>   depends on a floating-point loop
>   counter reaching a precise value. For
>   example, the following poorly-designed
>   loop never ends:
>
> ```
> for(double x = 0.0 ; x != 1.0 ; x += 0.2)
>     cout << x;
> ```
>
> The intention with this loop is to
>   output the value of `x` as it varies
>   from `0.0` to `1.0`; however, `0.2`
>   has no exact representation as a
>   binary floating-point value, so the
>   value of `x` is never exactly `1`.
>   Thus, the second loop control
>   expression is always false, and the
>   loop continues indefinitely.

Can someone please explain how the first code block runs while the second doesn't?

Comment: Note also that in the first example, you can't be sure whether loop body will be executed when x reaches 2.0. This might be important, but then you're better of with fixed point numericals.

Comment: "Can someone please explain how the first code block runs while the second doesn't?" Yes, someone can, and has: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: @stefaanv, what you say is generally true, but not specifically in the first example. Since `0`, `.25`, and `2` are all exactly representable (in IEEE754 and any other reasonable floating-point format), we know that `x == 2.0` will be true during the final loop iteration.

Comment: @stefaanv: A much easier fix (than switching to fixed-point) would be to pick a threshold value that falls comfortably between sequence values.  e.g. `for( double x = 0.0; x <= 1.05; x += 0.2 )`

Comment: To read `<=` in `x < = 2.0;` as an operator, you aren't allowed to put a blank between `<` and `=`. Therefore the edit.

Comment: Thanks @user unknown, I copied it from a PDF and I missed it while editing.

Comment: @afaolek: For reference, could you at least put the name (and/or a link) of the book in the question (before your quote)?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The first one will eventually terminate, even if `x` doesn't reach *exactly* 2.0... because it'll end up being *greater* than 2.0, and thus break out.

The second one would have to make `x` hit *exactly* 1.0 in order to break.

It's unfortunate that the first example uses a step of 0.25, which is exactly representable in binary floating point - it would have been smarter to make both examples use 0.2 as the step size. (0.2 isn't exactly representable in binary floating point.)

Comment: And. The traditional replacement for `a == b` for floats is `abs(a-b) < epsilon` where `epsilon` is less then expected precision. For example, `epsilon = 0.001` if all the used numbers are not more precise than 0.01.

Comment: @Pavel, since errors accumulate when adding a float multiple times, even testing against an epsilon might be risky. The error might be larger than you expect. Besides, it's just plain ugly.

Comment: @Mark, floating point equality is ugly, if I understood @Pavel right it's not meant as a replacement for the `<=` loop but for other cases where you just need something like `==`.  But then you always have to reason somehow about precision.  Often `epsilon` is even just used to specify a precision, e.g. aproximate `x` until a `abs(f(x)-f_target) < epsilon`

Comment: @Mark, right it is risky, but it has a very low risk. Anyway, if under some reason you need a guaranteed `==` (not in loops, of course, as Peer said), you will estimate your cumulative mistake and take an epsilon higher than that, but lower than demanded resolution. Almost everywhere it is possible.

Answer (score 15):

The first block uses a less-than-or-equal condition (`<=`).

Even with floating-point inaccuracy, that will eventually be false.

Answer (score 9):

This is an example of a broader issue - when comparing doubles, you often need to check for equality *within some acceptable tolerance* rather than exact equality.

In some cases, typically checking for an unchanged default value, equality is fine:

```
double x(0.0); 
// do some work that may or may not set up x

if (x != 0.0) {   
    // do more work 
}
```

In general though, checking versus an expected value cannot be done that way - you would need something like:

```
double x(0.0); 
double target(10000.0);
double tolerance(0.000001);
// do some work that may or may not set up x to an expected value

if (fabs(target - x) < tolerance) {   
    // do more work 
}
```

Comment: I like your explanation but how do I use that expression in the `for` loop? Thanks

Comment: It's not necessary for the `for` loop so long as your loop increment is sufficiently bigger than your tolerance to terminate the loop when you wish - in other words, just be sure that using `<=` results in the correct number of loops for your particular logic. I just posted this to expand on the topic a little.

Comment: @Christoffer Lette: this answer will not help the OP at all, as it is totally useless for checking variable counters in a loop. Whatever `tolerance` you pick, I can always pick `x` and `target` that will cause the counter to go into infinite loop. Tolerance checking is only useful if you wanted to check whether `x` converges to `target`; however if what you want to check is that something is until one value exceeds another then you have to do a comparison (i.e. `for (double x = ...; x < target; x += ...)`) instead of equality `for (double x = ...; fabs(target - x) < tolerance; x += ...)`).

Answer (score 6):

Floating point numbers are represented internally as a binary number, almost always in IEEE format You can see how numbers are represented here:

http://babbage.cs.qc.edu/IEEE-754/

For instance, 0.25 in binary is 0.01<sub>b</sub> and is represented as +1.00000000000000000000000 * 2<sup>-2</sup>.

This is stored internally with 1 bit for the sign, eight bits for the exponent (representing a value between -127 and +128, and 23 bits for the value (the leading 1. is not stored). In fact, the bits are:

[0][01111101][00000000000000000000000]

Whereas 0.2 in binary has no exact representation, just like 1/3 has no exact representation in decimal.

Here the problem is that just as 1/2 can be represented exactly in decimal format as 0.5, but 1/3 can only be approximated to 0.3333333333, 0.25 can be represented exactly as a binary fraction, but 0.2 cannot. In binary it is 0.0010011001100110011001100....<sub>b</sub> where the last four digits repeat.

To be stored on a computer it is roudned to 0.0010011001100110011001101<sub>b</sub>. Which is really, really close, so if you're calculating coordinates or anything else where absolute values matter, it's fine.

Unfortunately, if you add that value to itself five times, you will get 1.00000000000000000000001<sub>b</sub>. (Or, if you had rounded 0.2 down to 0.0010011001100110011001100<sub>b</sub> instead, you would get 0.11111111111111111111100<sub>b</sub>)

Either way, if your loop condition is 1.00000000000000000000001<sub>b</sub>==1.00000000000000000000000<sub>b</sub> it will not terminate. If you use <= instead, it's possible it will run one extra time if the value is just under the last value, but it will stop.

It would be possible to make a format that can accurately represent small decimal values (like any value with only two decimal places). They are used in financial calculations, etc. But normal floating point values do work like that: they trade the ability to represent some small "easy" numbers like 0.2 for the ability to represent a wide range in a consistent fashion.

It's common to avoid using a float as a loop counter for that exact reason, common solutions would be:

- If one extra iteration doesn't matter, use <=
- If it does matter, make the condition <=1.0001 instead, or some other value smaller than your increment, so off-by-0.0000000000000000000001 errors don't matter
- Use an integer and divide it by something during the loop
- Use a class specially made to represent fractional values exactly

It would be possible for a compiler to optimise a float "=" loop to turn it into what you mean to happen, but I don't know if that's permitted by the standard or ever happens in practice.

Comment: BTW, that layout was for a 32-bit float. For a 64-bit double the logic is exactly the same but there are more bits in the exponent and mantissa. (See link to website for fiddly details.)

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple issues with the example, and two things are different between the cases.

- A comparison involving floating point equality requires expert knowledge of the domain, so it's safer to use `<` or `>` for loop controls.
- The loop increment `0.25` actually ***does*** have an exact representation
- The loop increment `0.2` does ***not*** have an exact representation
- Consequently, it's possible to exactly check for the sum of many **0.25** (or **1.0**) increments but it isn't possible to exactly match even a single **0.2** increment.

A general rule is often cited: *don't make equality comparisons of floating point numbers.* While this is good general advice, when dealing with integers or  integers plus fractions composed of ½ + ¼ ... you can expect exact representations.

And you asked *why*? The short answer is: because fractions are represented as  ½ + ¼ ..., most decimal numbers don't have exact representations since they cannot be factored into powers of two. This means the FP internal representations are long strings of bits that will *round* to an expected value for output but not actually *be* exactly that value.

Answer (score 1):

General practice is that that you do not compare two floating point numbers, i.e.:

```
// using System.Diagnostics;

double a = 0.2; a *= 5.0;
double b = 1.0;
Debug.Assert(a == b);
```

Because of the imprecision of floating point numbers, `a` might not *exactly* be equal to `b`. To compare for equality you might compare the difference of two numbers with a tolerance value:

```
Debug.Assert(Math.Abs(a - b) < 0.0001);
```

Comment: There's no uncertainty; in your example, `a` _will not_ equal `b`.